# Add key and description of Enum in database

Tags: java, list, enums

I have a little problem in java and I didn't find any solution.
In class CustomerOrder I have a list of Enum type. I want to store in database key and description of enum. How can I do to save key and description?

Enum:

```
@Entity
public enum MenuList{
    SOUP(15.00),
    PIZZA_CHEESE_S(20.00),
    PIZZA_CHEESE_M(30.00),
    KEBAB(15.00),
    PASTA(18.00),
    FRENCH_FRIES(10.00),
    STEAK(25.00),
    SAUCE(3.00);
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
     ......}
```

Class customer order

```
@Entity
public class CustomerOrder {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private Integer noOfTable;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customerOrder")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private List<MenuList> productsOrdered;
    
    private Double totalOrder;
    @ManyToOne

    ....}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at AttributeConverter!

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html

```
 class MenuListConverter implements AttributeConverter<MenuList, String> {

    private final static String DELIMITER = ":";

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final MenuList menu) {
        return String.format("%s%c%s", menu.name(), DELIMITER, "put your id here");
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(final String value) {
        if( value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        final String name = value.split(DELIMITER)[0];
        return MenuList.valueOf(name);
    }
}
```

Then, in your entity,

```
@Column(name = "MENU")
@Convert(converter = MenuListConverter.class)
private MenuList menu;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could probably use a HashMap. Something like

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("SOUP", "Classic noodle Soup");
    put("FRENCH_FRIES", "Regular french fries");
}};
```

then you can get the descriptions with `map.get(KEY);`